# Sieve of Eratosthenes and his primes

Tags: c, primes, sieve-of-eratosthenes

This is my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    int number;
    int prime[200000] = { 0 };
    int i = 0;
    int j = 0;
    int number1[200] = { 0 };
    int t = 0;
    int count = 0;
    int newprime2[200][200];
    int counter[200] = { 0 };
    int square;
    int count1;

    while ((scanf("%d", &number) ==  1 ) && (number != 0)) {
        number1[count] = number;
        ++count;
    }
    count1 = count;
    for (count = 0; count < count1; ++count) {
        if (number1[count] < 0) {
            fprintf(stderr, "Error: Invalid input!\n"); 
            return 100;
            break;
        }
        for (i = 0; i < number1[count]; i++) {
            prime[i] = i;
        }
        for (i = 2; (i < (number1[count])); i++) {
            if (prime[i] != 0) {       
                for (j = 2; (j < (number1[count])); j++) {
                    {
                        prime[j*prime[i]] = 0;
                        if (prime[i] * j > (number1[count]))
                            break;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        t = 0;
        for (i = 2; i < number1[count]; ++i) {
            if ((prime[i] != 0) && (number1[count] % prime[i] == 0)) {
                newprime2[count][t] = prime[i];
                ++t; 
            }
        }
        printf("\n");
        printf("%i is made out of these primes\n", number1[count]);
        counter[count] = 0;
        square = 0;

        for (i = 0; i < t; ++i) {
            while (number1[count] % newprime2[count][i] == 0) {
                number1[count] = number1[count] / newprime2[count][i];
                square++;
            }
            counter[count]++;
            /* if number isn't made out of any of these primes*/
            if (!newprime2[count][i]) {   /*Why is this not working?*/
                printf("%i ", number1[count]);
            }  
            if (counter[count] == 1) {
                printf("%i^%d ", newprime2[count][i], square);
            }  else {
                printf("* %i^%d ", newprime2[count][i], square);
            }
            square = 0;
        }
    }
    printf("\n");

    return 0;
}
```

For example, my input is: `1 11 120 8 0`

**Output looks like this:**

```
1 is made out of these primes
11 is made out of these primes
120 is made out of these primes
2^3 * 3^1 * 5^1 
8 is made out of these primes
2^3
```

**But Output should looks like this:**

```
1 is made out of these primes
1
11 is made out of these primes
11
...
```

Statement `(!newprime2[count][i])` means that this array is empty right? So why it isn't working? And why I even can't use `gcc -pedantic -Wall -Werror -std=c99 -O3` ? Can someone help me?

Comment: For me `gcc -pedantic -Wall -Werror -std=c99 -O3` works  perfectly, your code compiles without errors or warnings.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See this part of your code:

```
    t = 0;
    for (i = 2; i < number1[count]; ++i){
        if ((prime[i]!=0) && (number1[count] % prime[i]==0)){
            newprime2[count][t] = prime[i];
            ++t;
        }
```

If `number1[count]` is `1`, then the body of the `for` loops *will not execute*, so`t` will keep its value (`0`). Consequently the body of the next loop

```
        for (i=0; i < t; ++i){
```

will not execute, too.

For number `11` the body of this loop *will* execute but it will do *nothing* as the condition in the `if` statement will be *always `false`*. So it results to the *same problem* - `t` will keep its value `0` with the same consequence.

Answer (score 0):

The line

```
if (!newprime2[count][i])
```

is not reached if `t==0` before the `for`-loop and that is the case if the input is prime or unity. Just check `t` and end there if it is zero.

Or check earlier if it is unity or it is in `prime` already.

I cannot repeat your problems with `gcc -pedantic -Wall -Werror -std=c99 -O3`.

Answer (score 0):

Your algorithm is both too complicated and approximate:

- You do not need to perform a sieve to factorize the numbers, you can just enumerate divisors, composite divisors will have a non zero remainder because their prime factors will have been removed already.
- The sieve is incomplete: you go to `200000` which would be overkill if `int` type is 32 bits (46341 would suffice) and would be too small if `int` is 64 bits.

Here is a simplified version:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) {
    int number, i, p, n, factors, count;
    int numbers[200];

    for (count = 0; count < 200 && scanf("%d", &number) ==  1; count++) {
        if (number == 0)
            break;
        if (number < 0) {
            fprintf(stderr, "Error: Invalid input!\n");
            return 100;
        }
        numbers[count] = number;
    }
    for (i = 0; i < count; i++) {
        number = numbers[i];
        printf("%d is made out of these primes\n", number);
        factors = 0;
        for (p = 2; p * p <= number; p += 1 + (p & 1)) {
            if (number % p == 0) {
                n = 0;
                factors++;
                do {
                    number /= p;
                    n++;
                } while (number % p == 0);
                if (n == 1)
                    printf("%d ", p);
                else
                    printf("%d^%d ", p, n);
            }
        }
        if (factors == 0 || number != 1)
            printf("%d", number);
        printf("\n");
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: @JozefSkála: did you provide input values? It works as expected on my system.

Comment: yes I did, for example 120 0. program stops and nothing is printed (I am using gcc -pedantic -Wall -Werror -std=c99 -O3 if that could be problem)

Comment: I tried that on both OS/X and Debian Linux.  It outputs `212 is made out of these primes
2^2 53`. Are you running it from the command line?

Comment: Yes I am.  Terminal(Ubuntu). Is that a problem?

Comment: No, it should not be. Did you cat and paste from the site or re-type? What happens if you type a negative number?

Comment: Firstly I re-typed it, because it didn't work I copypasted it. When I put negative numbers program keeps running and I am able to still put numbers. Weird, I really don't what is happening. Sometimes it just prints numbers that are not related to program, at least I think, but mostly it prints nothing. For example 120
5156
61560
4
650
54
65
0564
60
660
0
Output is: 4 650 54 65 564 60 660 4 650 54 65 564 60 660 4 650 54 65 564 60 660 4 650 4 650 54 65 564 60 660 4 650 54 65 564 60 660 4 650 54 65 564 60 660 4 650 54 65 564 60 660 4 650 54 65 564 60 660 4 650 54 65 564 60 660

Comment: I don't know if it's because of that but it seems that problem was when it didn't create exe programe.

Comment: Also thank you very much. I don't want to be rude but can I have just one more question? is there a way to do something like this: I input for example letter b or string (f.e. "momspaghetti) and program will react same as if it was a negative number?